# Logic of "bringing your own bomb on a plane reduce probability of there being another bomb"

Tags: probability

$$\mathbb P[\text{two bombs are on a plane}]\ll\mathbb P[\text{one bomb on a plane}]$$

So to make sure you're never in a plane with a real terrorist bring your own bomb (or the airline puts a real secured bomb on everyone of their planes if you care about "but what about security, they won't let you in with a bomb...").

What is wrong with this reasonning?

Comment: Independance...

Comment: There is the independence argument, but if you actually manage to enter a plane with a bomb, I'd say the conditioned probability of there being another bomb on that specific plane just increased, since I generally expect security to prevent entrance of any bomb whatsoever, but this time security screwed up. Also, someone else might have that same ideia.

Comment: You don't need to write $A << B;$ you can write $A \ll B.$ That is standard usage. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "independence" is the issue if you frame it like the questioner is. There's this random variable $B$ which is just "number of bombs on the plane". You can assume independence e.g. binomial with very small $p$ and its still literally true that $$P(B=2) \approx p^2 \ll p \approx P(B=1).$$

I would frame it as conditioning. You are confusing $P(B=2)$ with $P(B=2 \mid B \geq 1)$. i.e. by bringing a bomb, you are really interested in the latter quantity but you are thinking it is given by the miniscule probability $P(B=2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of a terrorist bringing a bomb is independent of whether you bring a bomb. Regardless of whether you bring a bomb or not, the terrorist has an equal chance of choosing to be or not be on that plane.